# Execution Policy getting reset?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to resolve an issue with `$(ESCAPE_DQUOTE(SRVR))` not being recognized by setting the `Process` scope to `RemoteSigned` based on answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/da276472-b5fd-4989-8940-74af90cf830a/powershell-script-fails-in-job-syspolicypurgehistory?forum=sqltools) by philfactor.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process
```

Then `Get-ExecutionPolicy -list`

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process    RemoteSigned
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine          Bypass
```

I open a new powershell now and `Get-ExecutionPolicy -list` returns `Process Undefined`!!
How come? Why is it resetting it?

Comment: The process scope is valid for the current process, not for all processes in general. If you open a new PowerShell you have a new process. In your case, you probably need to modify the user or machine scope.

Comment: @stackprotector `Set-ExecutionPolicy : Cannot set execution policy. Execution policies at the MachinePolicy or UserPolicy scopes must be set through Group Policy.` Damn it :/

Comment: You can use the `LocalMachine` scope to manually set the machine scope.

Comment: @stackprotector how

Comment: It's the default scope: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`. Or explicitly: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

Comment: @stackprotector but local machine is already set to bypass, which is even more elevated than RemoteSigned...that said, shouldnt everything else be set to bypass as well?

Comment: If a scope is `Undefined`, it will inherit from higher level scopes. So, in your case, you should be fine. I'm a little confused now. Do you actually have a problem with execution policies or did you just try to set the Process scope permanently (which won't work)?

Comment: @stackprotector i was trying to set the Process scope permanently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the `Process` scope permanently, it is only valid for the current process ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.1#parameters)):

> The **Process** scope only affects the current PowerShell session. The execution policy is saved in the environment variable `$env:PSExecutionPolicyPreference`, rather than the registry. When the PowerShell session is closed, the variable and value are deleted.

If a scope is `Undefined`, it will inherit its policy from a higher level scope:

> The effective execution policy is determined by the order of precedence as follows:
>
> - MachinePolicy. Set by a Group Policy for all users of the computer.
> - UserPolicy. Set by a Group Policy for the current user of the computer.
> - Process. Affects only the current PowerShell session.
> - CurrentUser. Affects only the current user.
> - LocalMachine. Default scope that affects all users of the computer.

In your case, `Process` will inherit from `CurrentUser` and `CurrentUser` will inherit from `LocalMachine`. Therefore, `Bypass` will be effective for the `Process` scope.

You can verify your current, effective execution policy by executing [`Get-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.1) with no parameters.

Comment: but its not displaying bypass for Process despite localmachine showing bypass... so inheritance seems bugged?

Comment: No, it just says, that it is not set explicitly and thus will inherit its setting.

Comment: Ok so I saw the updated answer, as I understand the Process scope policy change is not persistent except for the current session. Still, if localmachine is bypass, it should be returning bypass for Process but it's not doing that...weird